# decimal places and Pow function in c++

Tags: c++, decimal

Most likely a really simple question, please keep any answers easy to understand I'm still quite new at this:

I'm making a little app, and I need to use powers for a couple of calculations. After a little research I found the pow function in cmath, and have had a play. In the end i came up with this snipped, which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float dummy2, test(6.65);
    dummy2 = (float) pow((float) 3.57, test);
    cout << dummy2;

    return 0;   
}
```

and it returns the correct answer (4734.17), but only to two decimal places. I want 5 decimal places preferably.

What did I do wrong here? Am I using the wrong data type (floats)? Or is it a limit of whatever is in the pow function to using only 2dp?

I could, if it came to it just define constants with the values i want, since it's only going to be 4 or 5 sums that I need this precision on, but if it's possible to have the program calculate it that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. [These results](http://www.google.com/search?q=cout+decimal+places) and [these as well](http://www.google.com/search?q=cout+float+precision) have what you want, namely that you need to use setprecision() as a cout parameter.

Answer (score 6):

I would do as fbinder says, and use Doubles for greater precision.
To solve your problem, you have two options, C-style and C++ style.

**C-Style**

```
#include <cstdio>
printf("%.5f", dummy2);
```

**C++ Style**

```
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << setprecision(5) << dummy2 << std::endl;
```

OR

```
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << dummy2 << std::endl;
// continue to use cout to output 5 decimal places
```

Answer (score 3):

For a better precision you should use double. Doubles has 15 digits of precision against 7 for floats.

Comment: 15 and 7 decimal digits are only rough values. In particular, 7 for floats may be a little optimistic...